# Content CSS and compatibility with IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have inserted an icon with an image inside.

In chrome I see the icon

[image]

But in IE icon disappear.

Here's my CSS

```
<div class="infoIcon"></div>

.infoIcon {
    content: url('/assets/img/info-sign.png');
    background-color: #919191;
    width:15px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-left:10px;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: sub
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using HTML entity.

```css
.infoIcon {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="infoIcon">&#9432;</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I should have the 'i' like on the photo

Answer (score -1):

In css "content" applies to ::before & ::after pseudo selectors.

As to why it Chrome is showing the image, Chrome tends to be flexible with css syntax most of the times. IE and FireFox are not showing the image because it is not the right syntax.

Edit: 
Example
If you want to keep 'content' You'll have to move your content to 
.:before

```
.icon:before{
content: url('src');
}
```

However you'll need to scale your image to the right size. (Icon libraries use fonts where they can change the font-size easily)

Second option is continue as you are now but switch to background-image

```
.info{
background-image:url('icon.svg.png');
background-size: 100% 100%;
width:40px;
height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what could be the solution to that ?

Comment: U can use one of the many already existing icon libraries.  Like FontAwesome, if not I'm fabricating an example where it works!

Comment: or just use these pseudo selectors.

Comment: It show it now but width does not get applied to the picture. I get it in real size

Comment: Sorry for the confusion added the appropriate examples to solve the problem. Got mixed up while doing other tasks!